# Filling a External Data field (BCS) in a list trough Powershell

Tags: powershell, bcs

I have a list of which one of the columns is of the "External Data" type, linked to a BCS service.

We called this column "Organisation", and when I check the generated fields in powershell (with `$list.Fields | select Title`) I see that an Organisation and an Organisation_ID field was added to the column.

What I'm trying to do is to add a new item to this list and cause the BCS to retrieve data (trough an ID that I write to Organisation or Organisation_ID)

It would also be OK if I can trigger a workflow upon adding an item, that does this.

Any suggestions? Googling seems very hard on this matter.